# Exception in getReadbleDataBase() of SqliteOpenHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite

When I am using `android 4.0.3` I am getting an exception in `getReadbleDataBase()` method.`

```
   10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710): Couldn't open quytech.db for writing (will try read-only):
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 6 to 1
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:325)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:186)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:249)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at com.quytech.androidclient.data.MessageCountProvider.query(MessageCountProvider.java:156)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at com.quytech.androidclient.service.SmackableImp$6.processPacket(SmackableImp.java:1781)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection$ListenerWrapper.notifyListener(Connection.java:829)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$ListenerNotification.run(PacketReader.java:463)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-08 11:34:24.163: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(18710):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

but this is working fine in `android 2.0.3` .

first i am try to fetching query from dataBase.

```
Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(MessageCountProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,  MessageCountConstant.JID + " = ? AND "
                        + MessageCountConstant.To_USER + " = ? AND " 
                        + MessageCountConstant.DATE + " = ? ", new String [] {mConfig.userName,toJID,date},null);


                if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int recieveMessageCountColmnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageCountConstant.RECIEVE_MESSAGE_COUNT);
                    int sendMessageCountColmnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageCountConstant.SEND_MESSAGE_COUNT);
                    int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessageCountConstant.DATE);
                    String dateDB = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
                    int sendMessageCount = cursor.getInt(sendMessageCountColmnIndex);
                    int reciveMessageCount = cursor.getInt(recieveMessageCountColmnIndex);

                    updateMessageCountInDB(mConfig.userName, toJID, sendMessageCount+1, reciveMessageCount, date);
                }
                else
                {
                    addMessageCountInDB(mConfig.userName, toJID, 1, 0, date);

                }
```

after it it calls which i extends with ContentProvider.

and calls query() method.

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projectionIn, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    int match = URI_MATCHER.match(url);

    switch (match) {
    case MESSAGES:
        qBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        break;
    case MESSAGE_ID:
        qBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        qBuilder.appendWhere("_id=");
        qBuilder.appendWhere(url.getPathSegments().get(1));
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + url);
    }

    String orderBy;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) {
        orderBy = ChatConstants.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    } else {
        orderBy = sortOrder;
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor ret = qBuilder.query(db, projectionIn, selection, selectionArgs,
            null, null, orderBy);

    if (ret == null) {
        infoLog("MessageCountProvider.query: failed");
    } else {
        ret.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), url);
    }

    return ret;
}







private static class MessageCountDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quytech.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MessageCountDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    if (LogConstants.LOG_DEBUG) {
        infoLog("creating new chat table");
    }

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 

            + MessageCountConstant._ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + MessageCountConstant.JID + " TEXT," 
            + MessageCountConstant.To_USER + " TEXT,"
            + MessageCountConstant.SEND_MESSAGE_COUNT + " INTEGER,"
            + MessageCountConstant.RECIEVE_MESSAGE_COUNT + " INTEGER,"
            + MessageCountConstant.DATE + " DATE"

            +");"

            );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    infoLog("onUpgrade: from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);

    infoLog("onUpgrade: from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
    switch (oldVersion) {
    default:
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

Please help me..

Comment: change your Database_version to 6 or above. You cant downgrade the version of your db.

Comment: Hi Aprian . Thanks for reply. i mention database version 1 . its working in on other android version except android version 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> Can't downgrade database from version 6 to 1

The current database on that device *has* version 6.

If your app cannot handle downgrading (which was introduced in API version 11), you have to delete that database by clearing your app's data or by uninstalling the app.